# Why are there extra spaces in the file after copying text from one file to another in C?

Tags: c, file-handling

```
char c, cp;

FILE *input_file, *output_file;

input_file = fopen("d:\\input.txt","r");
output_file = fopen("d:\\output.txt", "w");

if(input_file==NULL){
    printf("cannot open the input.txt file.");
    exit(0);
}

if(output_file == NULL){
    printf("cannot open the output.txt file.");
    exit(0);
}

cp = fgetc(input_file);
while(cp!=EOF){
    fputc(cp,output_file);
    cp=fgetc(input_file);
}

c = fgetc(output_file);
while(c!=EOF){
    printf("%c",c);
    c=fgetc(output_file);
}

fclose(input_file);
fclose(output_file);
getch();
```

This is the code that I used while copying a text file.
In the input.txt file I have written "Hello how are you".

After executing the code, the text "Hello how are you" is copied to the output.txt file
but there are more than a hundred spaces after the copied text.
After the code below the program is not working:

```
cp = fgetc(input_file);
while(cp!=EOF){
    fputc(cp,output_file);
    cp=fgetc(input_file);
}
```

Code below the above code is not working.
What is happening? Please explain in detail. I am a beginner in C.

Comment: Try making `c` and `cp` `int`s not `char`s.  `EOF` is a magic value, not in the normal range of `char`.

Comment: See also: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eof-and-feof-in-c/

Comment: after changing c and cp to int, it doesn't solve the problem, till now there are lot's of spaces in output.txt file. Also the program doesn't run completely.

Comment: You should not try to read from a file opened in `"w"` mode...

Comment: Why not put your `printf` in the first loop, then ditch the second loop altogether?  Try and follow along with what your program thinks it's doing.  Even better, do something like `printf( "char is 0x%02x, or '%c'\n", c, c );`

Comment: changed to w+ but not solved

Comment: @EddInglis `EOF` is very often -1.  When `char` is _signed_ (quite often in windows worlds),  -1 **is** in the range of `char`.  Still `int  c, cp` is correct, for other reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must define `c` and `cp` as `int` not as char. `EOF` is defined as an integer value which is distinguishable from any char which may e.g. be read by `fgetc()`, which returns a value in the unsigned char range or EOF, not necessarily a value in the char range. (credits to @chux).

So `while( cp != EOF )` might not become true if `cp` is a char.

And for the second issue: if you want to read what you have written you must

1. open output.tx with mode "w+". "w" only permits writing, "w+" allows reading too but like "w" creates the file if it doesn't exist and truncates it if it does. See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) for further options and details.
2. call `rewind(output_file)` or `fseek(output_file, 0, SEEK_SET)` between reading and writing.

Comment: writing    rewind(output_file)    this solved my problem

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes of course thank you. I've fixed the typo and added your note to the answer

Answer (score 0):

you must close your output file to commit changes and be able to read a second time:

```
cp = fgetc(input_file);
while(cp!=EOF){
    fputc(cp,output_file);
    cp=fgetc(input_file);
}

fclose(output_file);
// .....        
c = fgetc(output_file);
```

Comment: and don't forget to reopen it